# I made this to print "Hello World !", but now I want to know other ways to print "Hello World !" in C++, simplify it if can

Tags: c++

I made this, but now I want to know other ways to do this, and simplify it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main()
{
    char* a[50] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "!"};
        
    std::cout << a[7] << a[4] << a[11] << a[11] << a[14] << " " << a[22] << a[14] << a[17] << a[11] << a[3] << " " << a[26];
       
    return 0;
}
```

Yes, I know `cout << "hello world !";` exists, but I want to try things differently.

Comment: 1) If we don't know what you are trying to do, we cannot say if it can be done differently: please clarify. 2) Stack overflow is not for Code Review. Please go to Code Review Stack Exchange. _(Side note `char* a[50]`: how many letters do you think the alphabet has?)_

Comment: 1) Right, I wanna print "hello world !" in many different ways.

2) Oh well thanks for letting me know.

Side Note: I didn't bother looking it up during the making of this code so I just use 50 as max xP

Comment: _"in many different ways"_. That's still very vague. What ways? Be explicit when you ask a question, or we cannot give a good answer.

Comment: You could for example take a look [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22618)

Comment: Multiple possible ways to print "Hello World !" in C++ other than cout << "hello world !";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "want to do thing differently" by addressing the letter by array index, yet want to simplify the array notation, I suggest this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    using namespace std;    
    string a="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!";
    cout<<a[7]<<a[4]<<a[11]<<a[11]<<a[14]<<" "<<a[22]<<a[14]<<a[17]<<a[11]<<a[3]<<" "<<a[26];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could just use `char[]` instead of `string` to save on a dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That also seems valid. We even need not to `#include <string>` then...

Comment: Oh, actually, by the current C++ standard, we can omit `return 0;` in the bottom too, as `return 0;` is assumed at end of the `int main()`!

Comment: @K.R.Park although you can omit it, the consensus of C++ teachers is that we should include it anyhow, just for consistency. So it's actually "better" that you include it.

Comment: @JHBonarius I remember that the Stroustrup, the creator of C++ said fine, therefore I do not have to feel guilt about omitting it.

Comment: @K.R.Park that might be (although I don't know if he still has this opinion. Opinions change.), but I think the modern consensus from people trying to teach C++ is that this inconsistency confuses students. And as Stack Overflow is used by many students as reference.